# Why rtrim remove trailing zeros?

Tags: php, trim

I to want trim `(+06)` from `12:00 (+06)`. So, I have used rtrim. I expect it returns me `12:00` but it actually returns `12:`

```js
<?php
  $str = "12:00 (+06)";
  echo rtrim($str," (+06)");
?>
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Are you only looking for the left part of the string and it's always the same number of characters, you could do this: $str = substr($str,0,5);

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I can. But also I want to know why trimming last zeros. Is it its actual behaviour?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do (without leading space before the left parenthesis). Rtrim strips ordinary spaces without defining it which seems to be the issue here. *To be honest:* I don't know why the rest is 12 and not 12:00 but without the space it works:

```
echo rtrim($str,"(+06)");
```

Are you only looking for the left part of the string and it's always the same number of characters, you could do this:

```
$str = substr($str,0,5);`
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept it as an answer :-)

Comment: (Not the downvoter, but) When a duplicate has been added to a question, the answer is on the duplicate.  So answering here can be seen as not necessary and some people see it as replicating an answer that has already been posted.

Comment: **To be honest: I don't know why the rest is 12 and not 12:00 but without the space it works** means that you just guess answered. There is no knowledge of why it works and that also means it can break at any time. Not an answer I would look at.

Comment: Ok Nigel and Andreas- Thanks! Now I understand the downvote. At the same time it as an answer that works and solves the OP's problem. I'm humble about my knowledge and when I don't know something to 100% I tell that and I think that's important for the readers who read the answer to know.

Comment: Completely fair. I too believe in honesty. But by reading the manual (or the linked question) you can easily see why this happens, and it's not because of the space as you think. Well, yes and no. But no.... Kind of

Comment: Ok! I will do that! The question wasn't flagged as a duplicate when I provided the answer. I will take a look :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works as expected as argument given to `rtrim()` defines which **characters** (NOT a string as a while) should be removed. As you specified `0` too, you got it removed as well. Conclusion is that you are using wrong function for your task - as you always want to remove fixed length substring from end of yourbstring, simply use `substr()` and cut from the end with negative length:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, -6);
```

Which is working no matter of source string length.